# WxPython, Linux : Unable to install wxformbuilder

Tags: python, linux, wxpython, centos7, wxformbuilder

I was Using wxFormBuilder and PyDev in Centos 7, for some reason I just reinstalled my OS and now i have configured Ecllipse with PyDev but i am not able to install wxFormBuilder.

I tried 3 different Type of installation

FIRST (1):
I Tried ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home%3A/Fisiu/SLE_11_SP1/x86_64/wxformbuilder-3.1.70-4.2.x86_64.rpm

it installed perfectly but when i try to open wxformbuilder it reply me

```
wxformbuilder: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk2u_flatnotebook-2.8_wxfb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

then i checked and copied that file from `/usr/lib64/wxformbuilder/libwx_gtk2u_flatnotebook-2.8_wxfb.so` to `/usr/lib64/libwx_gtk2u_flatnotebook-2.8_wxfb.so`

and 3 more files one by one and after that it is replying

wxformbuilder: Symbol _ZTV12wxBufferedDC' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking wxformbuilder: Symbol _ZTV10wxClientDC' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking wxformbuilder: Symbol _ZTV10wxMemoryDC' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking Segmentation fault (core dumped)

complete action are given below

```
[root@dell ~]# wxformbuilder 
wxformbuilder: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk2u_flatnotebook-2.8_wxfb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[root@dell ~]# cp /usr/lib64/wxformbuilder/libwx_gtk2u_flatnotebook-2.8_wxfb.so /usr/lib64/
[root@dell ~]# wxformbuilder 
wxformbuilder: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk2u_propgrid-2.8_wxfb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[root@dell ~]# cp /usr/lib64/wxformbuilder/libwx_gtk2u_propgrid-2.8_wxfb.so /usr/lib64/
[root@dell ~]# wxformbuilder 
wxformbuilder: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk2u_scintilla-2.8_wxfb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[root@dell ~]# cp /usr/lib64/wxformbuilder/libwx_gtk2u_scintilla-2.8_wxfb.so /usr/lib64/
[root@dell ~]# wxformbuilder 
wxformbuilder: Symbol `_ZTV12wxBufferedDC' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
wxformbuilder: Symbol `_ZTV10wxClientDC' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
wxformbuilder: Symbol `_ZTV10wxMemoryDC' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[root@dell ~]#
```

SECOUND (2):
After that I searched and found repository of rpm-sphere

```
[rpm-sphere]
name=RPM Sphere
baseurl=http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/zhonghuaren/Fedora_22/
gpgkey=http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/zhonghuaren/Fedora_22/repodata/repomd.xml.key
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

and tried to install from here

```
[root@dell ~]# yum install wxformbuilder
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.excellmedia.net
 * epel: epel.mirror.net.in
 * extras: centos.excellmedia.net
 * linuxtech-release: pkgrepo.linuxtech.net
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * remi: remi.check-update.co.uk
 * remi-php55: remi.check-update.co.uk
 * remi-php56: remi.check-update.co.uk
 * remi-safe: remi.check-update.co.uk
 * remi-test: remi.check-update.co.uk
 * rpmforge: mirror.smartmedia.net.id
 * updates: centos.excellmedia.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package wxformbuilder.x86_64 0:3.1.70-31.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) for package: wxformbuilder-3.1.70-31.1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: wxformbuilder-3.1.70-31.1.x86_64 (rpm-sphere)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
numactl-libs-2.0.9-5.el7_1.x86_64 is a duplicate with numactl-libs-2.0.9-2.el7.x86_64
[root@dell ~]#
```

and again failed..

THIRD (3):
and atlast I tried from source and run command

```
[root@dell ~]# make
```

and after 8 to 10 mins it says

```
/usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/debug.h:224:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘wxFORCE_SEMICOLON’
         wxFORCE_SEMICOLON /* just to force a semicolon */
         ^
/usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/debug.h:186:38: note: in expansion of macro ‘wxCHECK2_MSG’
 #define wxCHECK_MSG(cond, rc, msg)   wxCHECK2_MSG(cond, return rc, msg)
                                      ^
/usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/valtext.h:103:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘wxCHECK_MSG’
         wxCHECK_MSG( m_validatorWindow->IsKindOf(CLASSINFO(wxTextCtrl)), false,
         ^
stack.cpp
md5.cc
Linking wxFormBuilder
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mwindows’
make[1]: *** [../output/bin/wxformbuilder] Error 1
make: *** [wxFormBuilder] Error 2
[root@dell wxformbuilder-3.1.59]#
```

Now I researched 2 Days but still its not fixed, even i installed new OS on different different Desktop and tried there, but here also i found same issue.
Please help me how can I solve this issue. Thanks